# excel VBA for resizing ranges refered with listobject ranges

Tags: excel, vba, resize, range, listobject

I what to set a range into a variable to use in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

I want to refer to a cell which is 3 cells of top of a particular column of a list object.
this way:

```
set rOverlap = intersect(SRTbl.ListColumns(firstConceptColumn).DataBodyRange.iTem(1).offset(-3, 0).resize(0,3),target)
```

where firstconceptcolumn=9 (or whatever)

This would not work.

I do it in this way because If I ever decide to add columns at the beginning of the table the code will not need to be chage.
The first row of the listobject is not row1 but row5.
The first 5 rows trigger subroutines when the values change (upon entering data an pressing return)

[image]

I also tried it using headerRowRange with:

```
Set rOverlap = Intersect(SRTbl.HeaderRowRange(firstConceptColumn).offsset(-3, 0).Resize(, 4), Target)
```

which would not work neither.

Actually as a more fundamental question I am thinking what kind of data is:

```
SRTbl.HeaderRowRange(firstConceptColumn)
```

Is that a range?
why cant you use the following:?

```
SRTbl.HeaderRowRange("name")
```

Thanks a lot

PS: Everything what I say on stackoverflow is to resize the listobject itself.
PS2: I dont understand neither if there is a difference between these two guys:

```
.Resize Range("A1:B10")
```

and

```
 .Resize(1,10)
```

Jose Ferro

Comment: Start by removing your `offsset` typo...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim SRTbl As ListObject, header As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set SRTbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Set header = SRTbl.ListColumns("Name").Range(1, 1)
    Debug.Print header.Offset(-3).Resize(1, 2).Address

End Sub
```

---

Here is another:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim SRTbl As ListObject, header As Range, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")   
    Set SRTbl = ws.ListObjects(1)
    Set header = SRTbl.HeaderRowRange.Find("Name")

    If Not header Is Nothing Then
        If header.Row > 3 Then
            header.Offset(-3) = "Tada"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To refer to whole header width with offset of -3 rows:

```
SRTbl.HeaderRowRange.Offset(-3)
```

To simply resize found cell:

```
header.Offset(-3).Resize(1,2)
```

To resize to end of table from found cell

```
Debug.Print header.Resize(1, ws.Range(Split(SRTbl.HeaderRowRange.Address, ":")(1)).Column - header.Column + 1).Address
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am still looking for the solution where I refer only to a particular cell of a listboject and then transform it with a kind of method, i.e. offset &/or resize. Your solution works but it is very difficult to comprehense, which make very dangeous the code when it has to be modified and read by someone else. The quetion remains: refering to a particular cell : listobject.listcolumns(4).databodyrange.item(i) how do I get a range situatuated (a,b) cells from that one and which is (c,d) cells big.

Comment: My code is very straightforward (upto the last line - which I admit may seem more complicated).  header.Offset(-3)  gives you the required range. Then simply use .Resize on it. header.Offset(-3).Resize(1,2)  . You actually need my other lines of code to prevent potential errors being thrown which would be another problem for your users.

Comment: I have added an edit which I think is what you are after.

Comment: As you pointed out there are ways around to achieve the desired behaiviour, nontheless I arrevied to the conclusion that a expresion like: tbl4.HeaderRowRange(4).Offset(-4, 0).Resize(0, 4).Interior.Color = vbGreen its not meant to work, nor tbl4.HeaderRowRange(4).Resize(0, 4).Interior.Color = vbgreen. Your solution works but is a multy line solution. I am looking for a less "verbose" solution. One line. Tbl4.HeaderRowRange(4) is the range of a cell. offset(-4,0) moves it 4 cells up, and resize(0,5) should (applying common sense) make the one cell range into 5 cells range.

Comment: I assumed you wanted: Set header = SRTbl.ListColumns("Name").Range(1, 1)

Comment: As you pointed out there are ways around to achieve the desired behaiviour, nontheless I arrevied to the conclusion that a expresion like: tbl4.HeaderRowRange(4).Offset(-4, 0).Resize(0, 4).Interior.Color = vbGreen its not meant to work, nor tbl4.HeaderRowRange(4).Resize(0, 4).Interior.Color = vbgreen. Your solution works but is a multy line solution. I am looking for a less "verbose" solution. Tbl4.HeaderRowRange(4) = range of a cell; offset(-4,0) = 4 cells up; resize(0,5) =make the one cell range into 5 cells range. put all together= does not work. I think vba simply does not allow it.